# How to launch Apple wallet automatically for .pkpass file from Xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wallet

I have successfully created the .pkpass file and the api successfully returns the .pkpass file. In Xamarin forms I consume the API and try to add the .pkpass file into wallet but the wallet is not launching automatically.

The file which consumed from api via Xamarin app is working fine, there is no issue with the file. I have sent is as an email attachment and downloaded the attachment - the .pkpass file automatically opens with wallet app.

```
public async Task DigitalMembershipCardApple()
    {
        string accesstoken = _dataHelper.GetAccessTokenFromDBAsync().Result;
        try
        {
            _oHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesstoken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _oHttpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(Constants.Urls.DigitalMembershipCardApple + _dataHelper.GetPersonID()));

            byte[] filebytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), Constants.CISIMembershipCardFields.FileDownloadName);

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, filebytes);
            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, filebytes);
            }

            await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
            {
                File = new ReadOnlyFile(filePath, Constants.CISIMembershipCardFields.MimeTypeApple)
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I have also used the Xamarin essential launcher but that did not help.

[image] [image]
Much appreciate a quick help

Comment: Answer should be marked as AddToWallet code block below.

Answer (score 6):

```
//Called from Xamarin Forms, now on iOS Project,
public async void AddToWallet(byte[] passByteArray)
{
NSData nsdata = NSData.FromArray(passByteArray);
NSError err = new NSError(new NSString("42"), -42);
PKPass newPass = new PKPass(nsdata, out err);

PKAddPassesViewController pkapvc = new PKAddPassesViewController(newPass);

await     UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.
PresentViewControllerAsync(pkapvc, true);
}
```

Comment: Please add a prose introduction how this resolves the issue. (When trying to fix the indentation of the code presented: I find just bracketing it in lines containing `~~~` least troublesome.)

Comment: Excellent solution. Like the comment says, put this block of code into the iOS project. Use dependency service to call it from the Forms project.
How to access the view controller was most useful for me, thanks

Comment: strange that this code works once only and i have to delete the app and install it again for it to work. I tried deleting the added pass only but still it won't add again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use  Apple wallet before while when I read document of [PassKit in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/passkit?tabs=windows), in the [Adding Passes into Wallet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/passkit?tabs=windows#adding-passes-into-wallet) section, it says:

> Passes can be added to Wallet in the following ways:
>
> - Conduit Apps – These do not manipulate passes directly, they simply    load pass files and present the user with the option of adding them to Wallet.
> - Companion Apps – These are written by providers to distribute passes    and offer additional functionality to browse or edit them.   Xamarin.iOS applications have complete access to the PassKit API to create and manipulate passes. Passes can then be added to Wallet using the PKAddPassesViewController. This process is described in  more detail in the Companion Applications section of this document.

`Mail` is Conduit Application, it recognizes attachment as a Pass so the wallet app opens automatically .

`Your xamarin app` is Companion App, passes can then be added to Wallet using the `PKAddPassesViewController`. Read the file in your app won't open the wallet app.

My idea is you can download the file and follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/passkit?tabs=windows#companion-applications) to open the wallet app by using [dependency-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) in iOS project.

Answer (score 1):

I used a different approach that show a popup to add multiple passes or review them.
Call this using a dependency service:

```
public async void AddAppleWalletPass(byte[] passByteArray) 
{
    if (PKPassLibrary.IsAvailable) 
    {
        var library = new PKPassLibrary();
        var passes = library.GetPasses();
        NSData nsdata = NSData.FromArray(passByteArray);
        NSError err = new NSError(new NSString("42"), -42);
        PKPass newPass = new PKPass(nsdata, out err);
        PKPass[] pKPasses = new PKPass[] { newPass };
        await library.AddPassesAsync(pKPasses);
    } 
    else 
    {
        new UIAlertView("Alert", "Wallet is not available!", null, "Ok", null).Show();
    }
}
```